# How to set up buttons on calculator ios app with 2 labels one for a number and another for a letter value

Tags: ios, iphone, calculator

How to set up buttons on iOS calculator app with 2 labels: one for a number and another for a letter value?

I have it set up where the Buttons give back a value for each button pressed but I want to create another label under it to give a second value like a when you press 1 it will say 1 on the top label and "A" on the second label

```
import UIKit
enum modes{
    case not_set
    case addition
    case subtraction
    case equals
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var labelString:String = "0"
    var currentMode:modes = .not_set
    var savedNum:Int = 0
    var lastButtonWasMode:Bool =  false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func didPressPlus(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        changeMode(newMode: .addition)
    }

    @IBAction func didPressSubtract(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        changeMode(newMode: .subtraction)
    }

    @IBAction func didPressEquals(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString) else{
            return
        }
        if (currentMode == .not_set || lastButtonWasMode){
            return
        }
        if (currentMode == .addition){
            savedNum += labelInt
        }
        else if(currentMode == .subtraction){
            savedNum -= labelInt
        }

        currentMode  = .not_set
        labelString = "\(savedNum)"
        updateText()
        lastButtonWasMode = true        
    }

    @IBAction func didPressClear(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        labelString = "0"
        currentMode = .not_set
        savedNum = 0
        lastButtonWasMode =  false
        label.text = "0"        
    }

    @IBAction func didPressNumber(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let stringValue:String? = sender.titleLabel?.text

        if (lastButtonWasMode){
            lastButtonWasMode = false
            labelString = "0"
        }

        labelString = labelString.appending(stringValue!)
        updateText()
    }

    func updateText(){
        guard let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString) else{
            return
        }
        if (currentMode == .not_set){
            savedNum = labelInt
        }

        let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        let num:NSNumber = NSNumber(value: labelInt)
        label.text = formatter.string(from: num)
    }

    func changeMode(newMode:modes) {
        if (savedNum == 0){
            return
        }
        currentMode = newMode
        lastButtonWasMode = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second label in Interface Builder named `label2`, add a `label2String` variable in your class, update it where appropriate, and then set the `label2.text` to the content of `label2String` in the `updateText` method...

Comment: Lets say the buttons are A, B, C... How do I set it up where A will equal 1 and b = 2, When A is pressed A will appear on one Lable and 1 will appear on the other and How could I set it up where when you click a few buttons they add the value to each other like if you press A then B it will be 3 instead of 12  Thank You in Advanced